# conditionally replace nr within group

Tags: r

```
> DF<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,3,3),code=c("1","0","0","1,"0"))
> DF
  id code
1  1   1
2  1   0
3  2   0
4  3   1
5  3   0
```

Desired output:

```
      id code
    1  1   1
    2  1   1
    3  2   0
    4  3   1
    5  3   1
```

If `code=1` i want to replace all `code` within same `id` with 1. I´ve tried using the funcion `fill` but it just works woth NA values.

Best H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(out = +any(code == "1"))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
     id code    out
  <dbl> <chr> <int>
1     1 1         1
2     1 0         1
3     2 0         0
4     3 1         1
5     3 0         1
```

use base R

```
df$out <- with(df, ave(code, id, FUN = function(x) +any(x == "1")))

  id code out
1  1    1   1
2  1    0   1
3  2    0   0
4  3    1   1
5  3    0   1
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option via `ave`

```
transform(DF,
  code = ave(code, id, FUN = function(x) +("1" %in% x))
)
```

which gives

```
  id code
1  1    1
2  1    1
3  2    0
4  3    1
5  3    1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
library(dplyr)
#Data
DF<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,3,3),code=c("1","0","0","1","0"),stringsAsFactors = F)
#Compute
DF %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(code=ifelse(sum(any(code=="1"))!=0,"1",code))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   id [3]
     id code 
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 1    
2     1 1    
3     2 0    
4     3 1    
5     3 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
DF<-data.frame("id"=c(1,1,2,3,3),"code"=c("1","0","0","1","0"),stringsAsFactors = F)

for(id in DF$id){
  DF$code[DF$id==id] = max(DF$code[DF$id==id])
}
```

It replaces the values of `code` with the maximum value of this variable for the cases in which the `id`was identical. So, the output would be:

```
> DF
  id code
1  1    1
2  1    1
3  2    0
4  3    1
5  3    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Data.table solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[,code := ifelse(code == "1", "1", code), by=id]
```